Tracking Changes in an Excel Audit Trail
I've built an excel audit trail and would like to correctly track previous changes using VBA.
Currently, changes are tracked with "0" as the previous value but I'd like to ensure the cell value is used instead of the "0". Please see example below of the current log entries; I'd like for the second line to say "$E$6 changed from ND to Q":
Audit Trail Entries
I've used the following code in "ThisWorkbook":
Dim PreviousValue As String ' For Logging
Dim CurrentValue As String  ' For Logging
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    LogChange ("Closed " & ActiveWorkbook.Name)
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    LogChange ("Sheet Printed: " & ActiveWorkbook.Name)
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_NewChart(ByVal Ch As Chart)
    LogChange ("New Chart Created")
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    LogChange ("New Sheet Created")
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    LogChange ("Opened " & ActiveWorkbook.Name)
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    CurrentValue = "" ' Reset the current value

    If Sh.Name = "Audit Trail" Then Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next
    If Err.Number = 13 Then
        PreviousValue = 0
    Else
        CurrentValue = Target.Value
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' If there is no values, don't run the following. This fixed a custom macro to add 10 formatted blank lines in a detail sheet
    If PreviousValue = "" And CurrentValue = "" Then Exit Sub

    If VarType(PreviousValue) = VarType(CurrentValue) Then
        If CurrentValue <> PreviousValue Then
            If Err.Number = 13 Then
               PreviousValue = 0
            End If

            If PreviousValue = "" Then
                PreviousValue = "EMPTY"
            End If
            If CurrentValue = "" Then
                CurrentValue = "EMPTY"
            End If

            LogChange (Target.Address & " changed from " & PreviousValue & " to " & CurrentValue)
          End If
    End If
    PreviousValue = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Err.Number = 7 Then Exit Sub
    
    'Capture the What used to be in the changed cell
    PreviousValue = Target.Value
End Sub


If a user Copies and Pastes a value, you'll never track the change, since the only place you get the PreviousValue is on the SelectionChange.  Create a public Array variable and store the contents of the sheet's UsedRange in it.  Then you can create a local Array variable with the editted UsedRange data that gets populated on the SheetChange event.  Now all you have to do is walk the 2 arrays and find the differences and afterwards update the Public Array with the Local one.

Please explain what is intended by (eg) On Error Resume Next:    If Err.Number = 13 Then  If there's already a current error that would have already triggered an unhandled run-time error before your On Error Resume Next runs

building on Frank's point, I have done this as a before save event to generate the log each time someone saves, as opposed to every time a change is made, in case multiple changed, or corrections, etc., are made to the same line before the final save/close.

For something like this I usually will use the native "Review" tab on "Show Changes"
